# Risks migrating to python 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, migration

I am planning to migrate a large `python 2.7` codebase to `python 3.4` (nearly released). I have taken a look at the migration suggestions, and seems [a lot of work](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html). And there is one risk that worries me, difficult for  me to evaluate: I am depending on lots of third-party libraries. Could happen that I port my application to `python 3` and suddenly I realize that an important library is only working with `python 2.7`? I there any way to verify beforehand which libraries are working and which are not, starting from a `requirements.txt` file (`pip freeze`)?

Comment: Do you then mean an other way, besides manually going to their webpages ans looking?  Check this site for example https://python3wos.appspot.com/

Comment: As a side note, very few projects explicitly support 3.4 yet, since it's still only in rc1 status. In practice, anything that supports 3.3 will almost certainly support 3.4, but if "almost certainly" isn't good enough for you…

Answer (score 0):

> I there any way to verify beforehand which libraries are working and which are not, starting from a requirements.txt file (pip freeze)?

Sure. Just create an empty 3.4 project with that same requirements file, and try to use `pip` 3.4 to build and install it.

Or, even more simply, just `pip3.4` each requirement and see if it works. You can do this manually, or with a trivial bash or Python script.